# Why does my MP3 play in Android's Music app but not using MediaController?

Tags: android

I have an MP3 audio file that I want to play from my Android app.  I am using MediaController and VideoView like the answer to question [2961749](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961749). I get the error "Sorry this video cannot be played." But if I copy the file to /Music on my sd card, I can play it with the Music player app on Android. I've also tried just using MediaPlayer and it has a similar error.

Any ideas why this would be?  And, an anyone tell me what I need to do to play the audio?

Here's my code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.reading_layout);
topicGraphic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.topic_graphic);
videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);

Uri uri = Uri.parse("/sdcard/audio/mainidea.mp3");
mediaController = new MediaController(this);
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
videoView.start();
```

Comment: Why are you using a `VideoView` to play audio?

Comment: I was just trying to get the thing to play by following the example in the question 2961749. I'm not actually going to use VideoView.

Comment: Using MediaPlay and a MediaController didnot work for me.  Using the videoview seems to work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I figured it out. I had mounted my SD card to copy audio files from my PC. This meant my app could not access the SD card.  When I unmounted the SD card it worked. It would have been nice if the error message told me this but I'm happy to have audio playing.

Comment: Feel free to mark your own answer as accepted, so people will know the question has been answered.

Comment: But why do you use video view?

Comment: I tried to mark it answered but StackOverflow makes you wait 48 hours.

Comment: I was just trying to get it to play by using another example, which used VideoView.