# How can I show a MediaController while playing audio in Android?

Tags: android

How can I show a `MediaController` while playing audio file? I am creating an instance of `MediaController` and calling its `show()` method, but it is not showing.
Can any help me in sorting out this issue?

Comment: there is tick icon next to each answer's rating (on the left side, you will see it), just click it

Comment: Please accept one of the answers below. It helps show some appreciation for the people who took the time to answer your question.

Answer (score 93):

Here is an example of an Activity that uses MediaPlayer and MediaController to play audio.

```java
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;

import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;

public class AudioPlayer extends Activity implements OnPreparedListener, MediaController.MediaPlayerControl{
  private static final String TAG = "AudioPlayer";

  public static final String AUDIO_FILE_NAME = "audioFileName";

  private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
  private MediaController mediaController;
  private String audioFile;

  private Handler handler = new Handler();

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.audio_player);

    audioFile = this.getIntent().getStringExtra(AUDIO_FILE_NAME);
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.now_playing_text)).setText(audioFile);

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);

    mediaController = new MediaController(this);

    try {
      mediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioFile);
      mediaPlayer.prepare();
      mediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Could not open file " + audioFile + " for playback.", e);
    }

  }

  @Override
  protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mediaController.hide();
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.release();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //the MediaController will hide after 3 seconds - tap the screen to make it appear again
    mediaController.show();
    return false;
  }

  //--MediaPlayerControl methods----------------------------------------------------
  public void start() {
    mediaPlayer.start();
  }

  public void pause() {
    mediaPlayer.pause();
  }

  public int getDuration() {
    return mediaPlayer.getDuration();
  }

  public int getCurrentPosition() {
    return mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
  }

  public void seekTo(int i) {
    mediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
  }

  public boolean isPlaying() {
    return mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
  }

  public int getBufferPercentage() {
    return 0;
  }

  public boolean canPause() {
    return true;
  }

  public boolean canSeekBackward() {
    return true;
  }

  public boolean canSeekForward() {
    return true;
  }
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared");
    mediaController.setMediaPlayer(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.main_audio_view));

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        mediaController.setEnabled(true);
        mediaController.show();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Here is a layout that can be used with the code above:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/main_audio_view"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:orientation="vertical">
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Now playing:"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/now_playing_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Now playing.."
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: does anybody tried the above code?, it does not work, i dont hear the audio sound or show, yes i defined the `AUDIO_FILE_NAME ` something like this "mysite.com/talk/1.mp3"

Comment: I (at last) fixed the onStop method as suggested by @jp36. Thanks for the correction @jp36!

Comment: but how come the mediacontroller is not in the layout

Comment: I am having problems getting this code to work with the output from TTS; if you get chance could you look at this post please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20717236/play-wav-mp3-output-from-tts-with-mediacontroller  Thanks

Comment: @user229487 how to view the media player for more than three seconds  and also media player should hide only if we press back button.How can i  do this changes

Comment: And main_audio_view is for example a VideoView in the XML Layout.

Answer (score 21):

I still don't have enough rep to Comment so i have to just post this as an answer.

@user229487's answer

you need to add `mediaController.hide();` to the `onStop()` method.  If you don't do this and you happen to rotate the window or close the window while it is showing you will get a `Activity x has leaked window` error

New method should look like this

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mediaController.hide();
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.release();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I copied the code above from user229487 verbatim but couldn't get it to work.  Given I'm new to Android dev, I found out the hard way that you need to put an intent as well as a few other things.  I also don't exactly understand how the intent will work with a user interface (again I'm new), but will work on it.

Few things for other noobs like me to get the code above to work (I at least got it to not crash now and play a song :) ):

- Won't compile without this:

  `@Override

  public int getAudioSessionId() {

  return 0;

  }`
- To set audio manually: (change line to:)

  `public static final String AUDIO_FILE_NAME = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/MusicFolder/Song.mp3";`
- Setup intent
  Add this line:
  `this.getIntent().putExtra(AUDIO_FILE_NAME,AUDIO_FILE_NAME);`
  Before this line:
  `audioFile = this.getIntent().getStringExtra(AUDIO_FILE_NAME);`

Should compile and play song now.

Answer (score 0):

I am not yet allowed to comment ... therefore I write here.
The above code is excellent. I only needed to take out the

> mediaPlayer.prepare();

bit in the try catch, otherwise the activity would crash. Not sure what this bit should be doing, it is working very well without it. Thanks!!