# Android Audio controls

Tags: android, audio

Does anyone know what the class, intent is on Android so that if I wanted to stream an audio file, the whole control panel would come up. Play Pause volume ect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747139/how-to-show-mediacontroller-while-playing-audio-in-android

This link is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented the MediaPlayer and MediaController

Answer (score 0):

This should to it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri data = Uri.parse("http://..."); // or file:///...
intent.setDataAndType(data, "audio/mp3");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks, is there something that is in-app? so that its built in to the app.