# How to get Media Controller to work

Tags: java, android

I have a song within my application that I would like to be able to control via a Media Controller, I have the code which I believe would be accurate representaion of how to do this, however I get 2 errors within my code, I will give details bellow, could anyone please help me.

Error 1: The method setMediaPlayer(MediaController.MediaPlayerControl) in the type MediaController is not applicable for the arguments (MediaPlayer)

Error 2: The method setMediaController(MediaController) is undefined for the type MediaPlayer

The code I have so far:

```
MediaPlayer Song;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
         getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );
        setContentView(R.layout.billy);

        Song = MediaPlayer.create(BillyConnoly.this, R.raw.clip_1);

        MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
        mc.setMediaPlayer(Song);
        Song.setMediaController(mc);
    }
```

Comment: I think you'll find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747139/how-can-i-show-a-mediacontroller-while-playing-audio-in-android/5265629#5265629) example useful.

Comment: @crazylpfan I Get that that would be helpful, but that is really complicated for me to understand, I just started about a week ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thomas, I'll try to explain the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747139/how-can-i-show-a-mediacontroller-while-playing-audio-in-android/5265629#5265629) here.

First, you need to define your player, controller, and handler fields:

```
  private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
  private MediaController mediaController;

  private Handler handler = new Handler();
```

Next, you need to instantiate all of your appropriate objects (as you have done), as well as register an OnPreparedListener:

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);

mediaController = new MediaController(this);
```

Then, you prepare and start the mediaPlayer:

```
try {
  mediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioFile);
  mediaPlayer.prepare();
  mediaPlayer.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
  Log.e(TAG, "Could not open file " + audioFile + " for playback.", e);
}
```

When the mediaPlayer is prepared, the controller will be set:

```
  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared");
    mediaController.setMediaPlayer(this);

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        mediaController.setEnabled(true);
        mediaController.show();
      }
    });
  }
```

Does it make more sense now?

EDIT: This is how you would play a file from the res/raw folder:

```
int resID=getResources().getIdentifier("filename", "raw", getPackageName());
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,resID);
```

Comment: Thanks, It does make a bit more sense now, but I still don't understand how to get the audio file for playback if its in my raw folder

Comment: Ah, Thank you, you have been very helpful

Comment: No problem, let me know if you run into any other issues!