# Play wav / mp3 output from TTS with mediacontroller

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to output an MP3 or wav from TTS in android which then plays back via mediaplayer.  The TTS output to file works well and the mp3 file is available on the sdcard at the following location:

/sdcard/tmp/tmp.mp3

The problem I have is the audio file will only play once, if the user reselects the "Play" button then the file doesnt play.

The second problem I have is that the media controller isnt showing while the file is playing / user touches the screen.
The important parts of the code are below:

```
   //audio file playback here
    public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    public MediaController mediaController;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       //mediaplayer stuff

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);

        mediaController = new MediaController(this);
}
```

The play button onclick looks like this:

```
 String text = inputText.getText().toString();
                    if (text!=null && text.length()>0) {
                //  tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);

                    //trial synth to file here
                    HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, text);
                    String tempDestFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/tmp/tmp.wav";
                    tts.synthesizeToFile(text, myHashRender, tempDestFile);
                    //todo hand to media player for play pause etc
                    //todo handle delete of the file at some stage - creation of activity?

                    tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
                     public void onDone(String utteranceId){
                         // Speech file is created
                         // Initializes Media Player
                        Log.d("File created ", "init mediaplayer then call playAudio()");
                         initializeMediaPlayer();
                         //now play the audio
                        playAudio();
                     }

@Override
                public void onError(String utteranceId) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
                @Override
                public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                });
                }else{

                }
        }
```

The initialise for mediaplayer looks like this:

```
private void initializeMediaPlayer(){
    String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/tmp/tmp.wav";

    Uri uri  = Uri.parse("file://"+fileName);

    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

playAudio:

```
  private void playAudio() {
    mediaPlayer.start();
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    Log.d("MediaPlayer", " finished so release");
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                }
            });


        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
          super.onStop();
          mediaController.hide();
          mediaPlayer.stop();
          mediaPlayer.release();
        }

       public void start() {
          mediaPlayer.start();
        }

        public void pause() {
          mediaPlayer.pause();
        }

        public int getDuration() {
          return mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        }

        public int getCurrentPosition() {
          return mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        }

        public void seekTo(int i) {
          mediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
        }

        public boolean isPlaying() {
          return mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
        }

        public int getBufferPercentage() {
          return 0;
        }

        public boolean canPause() {
          return true;
        }

        public boolean canSeekBackward() {
          return true;
        }

        public boolean canSeekForward() {
          return true;
        }

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            Log.d("onPrepared", " is running");
            mediaController.setMediaPlayer(this);
            mediaController.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.layout.activity_main));

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                mediaController.setEnabled(true);
                mediaController.show();
              }
            });
          }
```

Finally the ouTouchEvent is here:

```
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
            mediaController.show();
            return gDetector.onTouchEvent(me);

            }
```

Logcat would seem to suggest the mediaplayer is being released after the file is played and is ready to play again, this is the logcat output when i try to play the file twice:

```
12-21 08:39:18.025: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26717): isPlaying: 1
12-21 08:39:18.025: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26717): getCurrentPosition: 2229 (msec)
12-21 08:39:18.025: V/MediaPlayer(26717): getDuration
12-21 08:39:18.030: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26717): getDuration: 6288 (msec)
12-21 08:39:22.320: V/MediaPlayer(26717): message received msg=2, ext1=0, ext2=0
12-21 08:39:22.320: V/MediaPlayer(26717): playback complete
12-21 08:39:22.320: V/MediaPlayer(26717): callback application
12-21 08:39:22.325: D/MediaPlayer(26717):  finished so release
12-21 08:39:22.325: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26717): release
12-21 08:39:22.325: V/MediaPlayer(26717): back from callback
12-21 08:39:22.330: V/MediaPlayer(26717): setListener
12-21 08:39:22.330: V/MediaPlayer(26717): disconnect
12-21 08:39:22.345: V/MediaPlayer(26717): destructor
12-21 08:39:22.350: V/MediaPlayer(26717): disconnect
12-21 08:39:26.465: D/File created(26717): init mediaplayer then call playAudio()
12-21 08:39:26.465: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26717): setAudioStreamType: 3
```

In summary my 2 questions are:

Why does the audio only play once and not each time the Play ImageButton is pressed?

EDIT:

Thanks to the part answer below by Dave the media now plays each time the user presses the play button.  The mediacontrols still are not showing on touch though.

How should I modify my code so the mediacontrols show standard play pause stop seek etc?

Thanks for the help, this is my first attempt with mediaplayer in android;

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pay more attention to the `MediaPlayer`'s [state machine](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) and design your interaction with it more carefully around that. To be specific, you cannot call `release` in the completion callback and expect to be able to use the same `MediaPlayer` again.

You can instead call `reset` in the completion callback and go through the code you have in `initializeMediaPlayer` again. Or alternatively, you can try seeking to zero to avoid re-preparing the source (although preparing a local file is negligible in terms of performance).

Edit:
About your `MediaController` problem... it can be a bit wonky in the emulator. I have a few suggestions.

1) Basically never use `getApplicationContext()`, especially not from inside an `Activity` (which already is a `Context`). (This probably doesn't help get the controller to show, but is just a general tip.)

2) You are passing `R.layout.activity_main` to `findViewById`. I don't think that's correct. It should be `R.id.___` for the ID of a view defined inside the layout. You can define the IDs with the `android:id` tag in the layout XML.

3) I could not get the controller to show when passing the ID of an empty `LinearLayout`. If you want to use a layout, you may need to put some kind of view inside it. I put a `TextView` inside it and viola, I had a controller. It doesn't show for long, so pay attention. There may be a parameter to set for the display timeout.

Comment: Thanks,  I will call reset and save the release for when the activity is complete.

Comment: @andy I edited the answer with a few tips. Hopefully that helps you get the controller working.

Comment: In case anyone else has similar problems to me the key was the R.id for the view I wanted the controller to appear in!  Thanks dave, perfect result!